# Is it possible to group td tags in a fieldset

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a html table and I want to group `<td>` into a fieldset. For ex in a row there are 16 columns, I want to group 8 into one fieldset (which has a check box to select these 8 cells) and group the other 8 into another fieldset (same with the checkbox so we can allow the second set of td tags to be selected)
Each row must have this arrangement. I am basically using asp.net mvc, razor, html5 etc. How to achieve this?

Comment: No. The only valid child element or `<tr>` is `<th>` or `<td>`.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me why they downgraded my question? Please state a reason for downgrading the question. Is it wrong to ask a question?

Comment: Not me, but perhaps the voter considered you had not researched it (and the lack of code showing what you tried does not help). There are lots of different selectors you could use such as giving the `<td>` elements a class name, or referring to the position - e.g. `$('tr').children('td').slice(0, 8)` to refer to the first 8.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What purpose would putting half a table in a fieldset serve?

Answer (score 1):

`<tr>` elements can contain only `<td>`s, `<th>`s and elements that aren't rendered themselves(`script`,`template`).

Here you can read the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element) for `<tr>` element, it clearly states the content of these elements can be ....

> Zero or more td, th, and script-supporting elements

And as of your case, you can use `classes` and `name` attributes to group the `checkboxes` together and then use `js` to handle the checking/unchecking, and leave the table structure alone.